# Compare latest record with previous record for updated columns from Audit log table

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I am facing scenario where i need to get the data from audit log table and show Old and new value.

For eg. Below is `audit_Log` table for Person

```
AUDIT_ID       PERSON_ID       OPERATION       NAME       ADDRESS       AGE     DOY 
    1           101             I           Prashant        Andheri     21      1991 
    2           101             U           Prashant1       Santacruz   22      1990 
    3           101             U           rashant2        Parle       23      1989
```

I want the latest value and previous value for all the columns as below,

```
PERSON_ID       COLUMNS      OLD_VALUE       NEW_VALUE 
101             OPERATION       U               U 
101             NAME            PRASHANT1       PRASHANT2 
101             ADDRESS         Santacruz       Parle 
101             AGE             22              23 
101             BIRTH_YEAR      1990            1989
```

Can anyone please help me to get this result from above table.

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: please can you post table structure like a table and not like a inline string, and post your result table? thk

Comment: Hi, I have update the table structure, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I try to find a function/ query to do what do you want but I do not found nothing. so I develop a procedure verify if work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _spManageAuditLog 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT AUDIT_ID, PERSON_ID, OPERATION, NAME, [ADDRESS], AGE, DOY, count(1)
    FROM dbo.audit_Log  
    GROUP BY AUDIT_ID, PERSON_ID, OPERATION, NAME, [ADDRESS], AGE, DOY;


CREATE TABLE #row (personId Int, operation char(1), name nvarchar(250),[address] nvarchar(250), age smallint,
doy smallint);


CREATE TABLE #out (PersonID Int, [columnName] nvarchar(250), OLD_VALUE nvarchar(250),NEW_VALUE  nvarchar(250));

--cursor variable
DECLARE
@AUDIT_ID   int,
@PERSON_ID  int,
@OPERATION  char,
@NAME   nvarchar,
@ADDRESS    nvarchar,
@AGE    smallint,
@DOY    smallint;


DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT AUDIT_ID, PERSON_ID, OPERATION, NAME, [ADDRESS], AGE, DOY
    FROM dbo.audit_Log  

OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @AUDIT_ID, @PERSON_ID, @OPERATION, @NAME, @ADDRESS, @AGE, @DOY

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    declare @countTempData int;
    select @countTempData= count(1) from #row;

    IF @countTempData=0 
     BEGIN
        Insert into #row VALUES(@PERSON_ID, @OPERATION, @NAME, @ADDRESS, @AGE, @DOY);
        --to debug
        --SELECT * FROM #row;
     END 
    ELSE
     BEGIN
        --do comparison previus row


        INSERT INTO #out VALUES (@PERSON_ID, 'Operation', (SELECT TOP(1) OPERATION FROM #row) , @OPERATION );
        INSERT INTO #out VALUES (@PERSON_ID, 'Name',(SELECT TOP(1) NAME FROM #row), @NAME );
        INSERT INTO #out VALUES (@PERSON_ID, 'Address',(SELECT TOP(1) ADDRESS FROM #row), @ADDRESS );
        INSERT INTO #out VALUES (@PERSON_ID, 'Age',(SELECT TOP(1) AGE FROM #row), @AGE );
        INSERT INTO #out VALUES (@PERSON_ID, 'BirthYear',(SELECT TOP(1) DOY FROM #row), @DOY );


        --new item became temp item
        TRUNCATE TABLE #row
        INSERT INTO #row VALUES(@PERSON_ID, @OPERATION, @NAME, @ADDRESS, @AGE, @DOY);
        --to debug
        --SELECT * FROM #row;

     END

    -- Get the next.
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @AUDIT_ID, @PERSON_ID, @OPERATION, @NAME, @ADDRESS, @AGE, @DOY
END 
CLOSE myCursor;
DEALLOCATE myCursor;

SELECT * FROM #out;


END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, [COLUMNS], OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE
FROM(
    SELECT TOP 2 PERSON_ID, ( CASE ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY AUDIT_ID DESC )) WHEN 1 THEN 'NEW_VALUE' ELSE 'OLD_VALUE' END ) AS [Version],
        CAST( OPERATION AS VARCHAR( 100 )) AS OPERATION, CAST( NAME AS VARCHAR( 100 )) AS NAME,
        CAST( ADDRESS AS VARCHAR( 100 )) AS ADDRESS, CAST( AGE AS VARCHAR( 100 )) AS AGE, CAST( DOY AS VARCHAR( 100 )) AS DOY
    FROM audit_Log
    WHERE PERSON_ID = 101
    ORDER BY AUDIT_ID DESC ) AS SourceData
UNPIVOT(
    COL_VALUE FOR [COLUMNS] IN( NAME, ADDRESS, OPERATION, AGE, DOY )
    ) AS UnpivotColumns
PIVOT(
    MIN( COL_VALUE ) FOR [Version] IN( [NEW_VALUE], [OLD_VALUE] )
    ) AS PivotOldNew
```

Notes:

- You need to convert all of your audit column values to a common type. I
  chose `VARCHAR( 100 )` but you may need to choose something else.
- This code also works when only one audit record exists. In this case it
  will show `NULL` for `OLD_VALUES`

References:

http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/unpivot-multiple-columns.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

EDIT: excluded erroneous code at the end of the query

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the reply, but query is not working and giving syntax error. I didn't understand the approach.

Comment: @user1150365 I have removed the last 2 lines which were copy/pasted erroneously